# BUILD FAILED when trying to install Pyenv3 on OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew, pyenv

So I've been trying to install Pyenv using Homebrew, but kept getting a failed build error and this message:

> Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/bb/n2w9d9210qzg_y3_c4cm92tr0000gn/T/python-build.20220507224423.63876

I've included the last two lines of the log:

> configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX 
>  make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Let me know if you need more info. Thank you.

Comment: This was the guide I was using: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install pyenv:**

```
brew install pyenv
```

For Python 3, let's  install 3.10.4.

```
pyenv install 3.10.4
```

To see the list of the Python versions

```
pyenv versions
#Python 3.10.4
```

You can update to new version, and optionally uninstalling the old version by

```
pyenv install new.python.version

pyenv global new.python.version

pyenv uninstall old.python.version
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not sure what I was doing wrong..

Comment: Uninstall all and reinstall